Custom Post Type posts not getting picked up in archive widgets
I have added a couple of CPTs along with the existing "Posts" post type. I have added snippets to have these CPT appear in Searches, Author Page as well as in "All Listings". However I am not able to get them in the widgets - Recent Posts, Archives (monthly). Can someone provide me with code snippets to add them in fucntions.php?

Some more information would help. Where you've added them, do they appear in the same feed as Posts, or listed separately?

I added this snippet to appear them in the same feed as posts - add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'story', 'gallery', 'webseries', 'novel', 'episode' ) );
return $query;
}
